# Set List Box width to fill column width in Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 list boxes as part of my html. I would like **list box to fill the column, so the width of the ListBox will be same as the width of the column**, but I am not able to do so.
In 'col-md-12', the width of list box should be almost the width of the screen.
I have tried this:

1. Set width of the list box "width:100%" on each individual listbox.
2. Set width of parent div  "width:100%" on each individual listbox.
3. I have also tried to use container-fluid on root div.

but no luck.

I do not want to set the width to static size ('width: 550px').

```
<div class="form-horizontal container">
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select Class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="font-size:large">
                <option value="1">Test234</option>
                <option value="3">Test123</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select Class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="font-size:large">
                <option value="26">SVC1</option>
                <option value="27">SVC2</option>
                <option value="28">SP1</option>
                <option value="29">PN1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
        <select Class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="items" style="font-size:large"></select>
    </div>   
</div>
```

**Update #1:**

As I did not mention in this question that this was a part of MVC view, here is a little hint, which I have blindly overlooked and spend hours trying to fix. 
Mine solution worked perfectly OK, but when you create new MVC 5 website project in Visual Studio 2013, it creates it's own css file called Site.css. In this file it has line which looks like this:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input, select, textarea
{
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

which, whatever you do (in my case pulling my hair), will not let you change width. So after commenting this out, all worked fine.

Hope this will help someone...

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been searching for the last 2 hours.
Never thought checking site.css :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <hr />
    <div class="panel row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="font-size:large">
                <option value="1">Test234</option>
                <option value="3">Test123</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="font-size:large">
                <option value="26">SVC1</option>
                <option value="27">SVC2</option>
                <option value="28">SP1</option>
                <option value="29">PN1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
        <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="items" style="font-size:large"></select>
    </div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5x9tohmq/1/)

Comment: thank you. this worked. as you were the first one, I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put "form-group col-md-12" in a child div of "row", like it's supposed to be.
Same goes for the first two, make form-group a child div and leave row by itself.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eewjrx41/2/)

```
<div class="form-horizontal container">
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select Class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="font-size:large">
            <option value="1">Test234</option>
            <option value="3">Test123</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class=" col-md-6">
        <select Class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="font-size:large">
            <option value="26">SVC1</option>
            <option value="27">SVC2</option>
            <option value="28">SP1</option>
            <option value="29">PN1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <select Class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="items" style="font-size:large"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width 100% of select tag:

```
select {
     width:100% !important;
}
```